# adding html attributes without a value using .net

Tags: html, .net

I want to add a `multiple` `attribute` to a `select`  in `.net`. I have done this:

```
If MultiSelect Then
  drpSelect.Attributes.Add("multiple", "true")
End If
```

Though strictly speaking the html should be just multiple.

Comment: If you want add as answer Ill accept and vote. If you are not that insecure then please just accept my thanks Hans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the "boolean" html attributes (the ones that should consist of just a name without a value, like `required` or `multiple`) an accepted alternative is to use `name="name"`, like `multiple="multiple"`.

In your case you should code

```
drpSelect.Attributes.Add("multiple", "multiple")
```

See also [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/intro/sgmltut.html#didx-boolean_attribute):

> Boolean attributes may legally take a single value: the name of the
>   attribute itself.